# AUI Checkbox not showing as checked but value is true

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, checkbox, yui

I have a checkbox .

```
<aui:input name = "enable" id = "enable" type="checkbox" label= 'Enable'  onchange='handleClick(this);' />
```

I load the previous state of the checkbox on page load. When the previous state is checked, I do the following.

```
var namespace = "<portlet:namespace/>";
window.onload = function() {
    var cb = document.getElementById(namespace+ "enable");
    cb.checked = true;
    alert("state: " + cb.checked);
    //do something
};
```

The alert shows me the checkbox is `true` and it executes the code that follows. However, the view does not show the checkbox to be checked! What am I missing?

Comment: what is that "previouslychecked"?

Comment: It's a variable that I set in my jsp making a call to the library. That is not a issue.

Comment: what is `namespace+ "enable"` , what it returns?

Comment: It can be issue , cuz . if its true , you set already   cb.checked = true; and alert that so u get "state : true" .

Comment: it returns the checkbox.

Comment: sharing a Fiddle would make this easier

Comment: ya share a demo please

Comment: I haven't used jsfiddle before. Is it possible with an `aui:input` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad thing or the good thing with `AUI Input` is,  it appends **Checkbox** automatically to the id of `input:checkbox`.

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="handleClick(this);" value="true" onclick="Liferay.Util.updateCheckboxValue(this); " name="_manageorganization_WAR_manageorganizationportlet_enableCheckbox" id="_manageorganization_WAR_manageorganizationportlet_enableCheckbox" class="aui-field-input aui-field-input-choice">
```

And in your case with your `"<portlet:namespace/>";`, it generates id as :

```
namespace+ "enableCheckbox"
```

So use it as :

```
var namespace = "<portlet:namespace/>";
window.onload = function() {
    var cb = document.getElementById(namespace+ "enableCheckbox");
         cb.checked = true;
        alert("state: " + cb.checked);
         //do something
};
```

And it will work.